# Как использовать значение в следующей формуле?

Tags: javascript

подскажите есть формула

```
a * b / 12 / 100 = result
```

Мне нужно использовать данную формулу 12 раз (повторение) .

Т. е. результат первой формулы использовать в следующей для сложения с `а`:

```
1) a * b / 12 / 100 = result 

2) (a + result) * b / 12 / 100 = result

3) (a + result) * b / 12 / 100 = result

4) (a + result) * b / 12 / 100 = result
```

И т. д.

При этом количество повторений может изменятьcя .

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Может быть, циклы помогут?

Comment: Да, но как в цикле использовать результат первой формулы в следующей

Comment: Вначале result=0

Answer (score 0):

```js
const times = 4;
// вместо result будем использовать c
const foo = (a, b, с) => (a + с) * b / 12 / 100;

const a = 10; // случайные значения
const b = 20; // случайные значения
let result = 0;
// Используем цикл, для повторного выполнения функции
for(let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
  result = foo(a, b, result)
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: С каждым повторением оно перезаписывает result?

Comment: Получается не правильные вычисления . При формуле (1000000 + result) * 0.15 / 12

Первые 2 значения верны а 3 4 получается какая то дичь . Не могу понять в чем

12500

12656.25
12658.203125
12658.2275390625

Должно быть 
12500
12656.25
12814,453125
12974,6337890625

Comment: да, перезаписывает. Формула каждый раз одна и та же выполняется, которую вы написали